# jQuery element styles are not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a bootstrap carousel slider in my HTML. When loading and reloading the page, it takes a second to load the carousel image and meantime all the image borders and carousel indicators are there. Then I created a code to invisible all the borders and elements of carousel until loading the image. This is working perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge and Opera but doesn't working in Safari.

```js
$(".carousel-img").on('load', function() {
  $(".carousel-indicators").css({
    display: "-webkit-flex",
    display: "-webkit-box",
    display: "-moz-flex",
    display: "-moz-box",
    display: "-ms-flexbox",
    display: "flex",
    "flex-direction": "row"
  });
}).attr("src", $(".carousel-img").attr("src"));
```

```css
.carousel-indicators {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/00f/ff0" alt="..."></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/0f0/f0f" alt="..."></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/f00/0ff" alt="..."></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/00f/ff0" alt="..." class="carousel-img">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/0f0/f0f" alt="..." class="carousel-img">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/f00/0ff" alt="..." class="carousel-img">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

In safari, This carousel-indicators are not showing at all. All the other browsers are showing it correctly. How to fix it?

Comment: Check: 1. is the CSS of `.carousel-indicators` changed at all? 2. Is the `load` event callback function even called? Validate by add a `console.log()` at the start of the function. 3. What happens, if you completely clear your browser cache in Safari? It may be that the load event does not work correctly on cached images.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's a mistake. I edited the code

Comment: @HerrSerker After clearing browser history in safari and load the page, It is working. After reloading the page, the carousel will be gone. To see it, again I have to clear the browser data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

1. I moved some code in functions
2. I moved CSS from JS to CSS
3. I check for load event as well as complete status for every img
4. If complete or loaded I remove that image from the queue
5. If queue empty, show indicators

```js
console.clear()

jQuery(function($) {
  var $queue = $(".carousel-img")
  var total = $queue.length;

  $queue
    .each(checkLoaded)    
  $queue
    .on('load', onloadImage)
  
  
  function checkShowIndicators() {
    if ($queue.length === 0) {
      $(".carousel-indicators").addClass('after-load')
    }
  }
  
  function onloadImage() {
    console.info('loaded: ' + $(this).attr('src'))
    $queue = $queue.not(this)
    checkShowIndicators();
  }
  
  function checkLoaded() {
    if ($(this).get(0).complete) {
      console.info('complete: ' + $(this).attr('src'))
      $queue = $queue.not(this)
      checkShowIndicators();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.carousel-indicators{
  display: none;
}
.carousel-indicators.after-load {
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-moz-flex;
  display:-moz-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/00f/ff0" alt="..."></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/0f0/f0f" alt="..."></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/f00/0ff" alt="..."></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/00f/ff0" alt="..." class="carousel-img">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/0f0/f0f" alt="..." class="carousel-img">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/f00/0ff" alt="..." class="carousel-img">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you try to add the line `display:"-webkit-flexbox",`

```
$(".carousel-img")
    .on('load', function() {
        $(".carousel-indicators").css({ display:"-webkit-flex",
                                        display:"-webkit-box",
                                        display:"-webkit-flexbox",
                                        display:"-moz-flex",
                                        display:"-moz-box",
                                        display:"-ms-flexbox",
                                        display:"flex",
                                        "flex-direction":"row"
                                        });
    })
    .attr("src", $(".carousel-img").attr("src"));
```

Comment: Used that too. But still the problem is there. But if I clear browser history and reload the page, it shows the carousel. After reloading, it will disappear again

Answer (score 0):

Please try to look like.

```
$(".carousel-img")
.on('load', function() {
    $(".carousel-indicators").css({ display:"-webkit-flex",
                                    display:"-webkit-box",
                                    display:"-moz-flex",
                                    display:"-moz-box",
                                    display:"-ms-flexbox",
                                    display:"-webkit-flexbox",
                                    display:"flex",
                                    "flex-direction":"row"
                                    });
})
.attr("src", $(".carousel-img").attr("src"));
```

Comment: What did you change? It seems to be just the addition of `display: -webkit-flexbox` as javimovi already answered.

Comment: Sorry, same time typing answer. but he posts first.